# REST API pagination with ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Im using copy activity for API calls to fetch some data. Begining of the copy activity, I retrive the new access token and then pass it to it.

But I have one problem with the bigger tables. API access token is valid only for 10 mins. But this big tables take longer than 10 mins. So by the time is has to move on next page token is expired and pipeline fails. I can request to new access token but no idea how can i pass it while copy activity is running.

My pipeline looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCUkZ.png)

Adding the LinkedService:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMMgW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the accessToken activity inside Foreach Loop ,also remove the one which you add outside.So that before each copy activity it will get the new access token.